# Google cloud task divide into subtasks by firebase data

Tags: php, firebase, google-cloud-tasks

I have a **google task** which gets all companies from my **firebase database**. I then go through each of those companies in a loop and call additional task for updating each specific company. My problem is that my companies count is increasing and when doing foreach like this i can get into **memory limit** issues. Here is the actual code for calling the tasks and subtasks:

```
$router->get('companies', function () use ($router) {

    $slackDataHelpersService = new \App\Services\SlackDataHelpersService();
    $companiesDocuments = $slackDataHelpersService->getCompanies();

    foreach ($companiesDocuments->documents() as $document) {
        $cid = $document->id();
        createTask('companies', 'updateCompany', "{$cid}");
    }

    return res(200, 'Task done');
});
```

How can i separate my initial companies documents into chunks and call a task for each of those chunks? For example, a task that will go through every 100 documents instead of the whole list?

Here is what i tried without success(i used members in this case):

```
$router->get('test2', function () use ($router) {

    $db = app('firebase.firestore')->database();

    $membersRef = $db->collection('companies')->document('slack-T01L7H2NDPB')->collection('members');
    $query = $membersRef->orderBy('created', 'desc')->limit(10);

    $perPage = 10;
    $batchCount = 10;
    $lastCreated = null;

    while ($batchCount == $perPage) {

        $loopQuery = clone $query;
        if ($lastCreated != null) {
            $loopQuery->startAfter($lastCreated);
        }
        $docs = $loopQuery->documents();
        $docsRows = $docs->rows();
        $batchCount = count($docsRows);

        if ($batchCount > 1) {
            $lastCreated = $docsRows[$batchCount - 1];
        }
        echo $lastCreated['created'];
        //createTasksByDocs($docs);
    }
    //return res(200, 'Task done');
});
```

Comment: Are you asking [how to split a list into chunks in php?](https://www.google.com/search?q=how+to+split+a+list+into+chunks+in+php)

Comment: no, i need to split it into chunks in firebase and then call other tasks in that way.

Comment: So how to [paginate data in Firestore](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/query-cursors) then?

Comment: Yes, but i cant suceed in this way i am trying to do. I dont understand why, it would be good if someone pointed me in the right direction. I edited my question with new code.

Comment: I'm not a PHP expert, but at first glance the way you set and use `$lastCreated` looks good to me. You might want to echo that value for every doc, and then include that updated code and its output in the question - in hopes that somebody else spots what might be going wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up making a function which uses a while loop and loops until it reaches the limit:

```
function paginateCollections($ref, $limit, $functionName)
{
    $query = $ref->orderBy('created', 'desc')->limit($limit);

    $perPage = $limit;
    $batchCount = $limit;
    $lastCreated = null;

    while ($batchCount == $perPage) {

        $loopQuery = clone $query;
        if ($lastCreated != null) {
            $loopQuery = $loopQuery->startAfter([$lastCreated]);
        }
        $docs = $loopQuery->documents();
        $docsRows = $docs->rows();
        $batchCount = count($docsRows);

        if ($batchCount > 1) {
            $lastCreated = $docsRows[$batchCount - 1]['created'];
        }

        if (function_exists($functionName)) {
            $functionName($docs);
        }
    }
}
```